# Issues With Tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat

I am newbie in Tomcat(8) and having some issues with Tomcat. i want it to display the default Tomcat homepage like the way it was when i installed it for the first time. I am running/compiling some maven project in netbeans and it seems they are automatically deployed to Tomcat.

I have looked into the folders of Tomcat i can't see the app anywhere but its "index.html" file displays when i launch "localhost" . This makes the `index.html` file of the maven application displays as the default localhost page.

At the moment i want the localhost to display the default Tomcat page like it was when i first installed it. 
I have changed my `"C:\servers\tomcat8\conf\Catalina\localhost\ROOT.xml"` file to the following but it is not working::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Context antiJARLocking="true" docBase="C:\projects\spring\PersistenceWithHibernate\target\PersistenceWithHibernate-1.0-SNAPSHOT" path="" /-->
<Context antiJARLocking="true" docBase="C:\servers\tomcat8\webapps\examples" path=""/>
```

I have pointed the docBase to `docBase="C:\servers\tomcat8\webapps\manager"` and comment out the one that is displaying the `index.html` page,
yet its not working

How do i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain if i understand what you are asking for, could you clarify the question up a bit?

But when you do a clean tomcat install, the default directory where the projects are deployed at, is under the tomcat install folder ../tomcat/webapps/ROOT.

The manager part is a tool to manage the tomcat, you sohuldn't need to configure it's docbase.

Check http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ for reference. At least the few first chapters, its all explained.

Comment: @Observer thanks for your reply. when you install tomcat for the first time and go to localhsot, you get a default tomcat homepage. It is this homepage that i want to go to now. On my part when i go to localhost, i get the index.html file that is in the maven project i talked about. I want my localhost to display the default tomcat homepage. it can be the manager you are talking about

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what (many things) you did to get to where you are. If you unzip a default tomcat installation next to your current installation and compare the directories, you'll be able to spot the differences.

As this is probably not what you want to hear: The default tomcat installation has the default web application in webapps/ROOT (because there needs to be an encoding for the "empty" context name, answering on `www.example.com/`

Restoring the default webapp might be as simple as restoring the original ROOT.xml, remove that file, restore webapps/ROOT or anything in combination.

Frankly, your problem description *"but it is not working"* doesn't really help. If this answer doesn't solve your problem, you might want to give more detailed description than that. What *do* you actually see. But then, you might as well state what differences you find between the original and your installation.